# Why this vhosts configuration keeps redirect other domains to one

Tags: nginx, configuration, virtualhost

I'm trying to add a second domain to nginx. It's ok to access static files like css in  domain2.com but visits to php scripts (e.g domain2.com/index.php) will be 302 redirect to domain1.com (e.g domain1.com/index.php) so I thought the break point must be in the `location ~ \.php$` section, but I can't make sure where it is. I have been stuck here for a long time, where am i doing wrong?
[OS:windows 2008; Nginx:1.0.12]

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen         80;
        server_name     _;
        server_name_in_redirect  off;
        location / {
            root  F:/Web/nginx/html/;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
    include F:/Web/nginx/vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

F:/Web/nginx/vhosts/domain1.com.conf

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
            root   F:/domain1;
        index  index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  F:/domain1/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

F:/Web/nginx/vhosts/domain2.com.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  domain2.com;
charset utf-8;

location / {
    root   F:/domain2;
    index  index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  F:/domain2/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I found the reason.It's not the nginx configuration problem, it's php-cgi config. I set `doc_root='F:/domain1'` so it keeps redirecting.

Hope can help anyone who encounter this question again.